# PySpark DataFrame generated by filter - where is it stored?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

This is probably a basic question for any software architects, but I struggle with the concept.

Let's say I have a big Spark DataFrame stored on hdfs. I now do a filtering operation like this:

```
df_new = my_big_hdfs_df.where("my_column='testvalue'")
print(type(df_new))
```

> class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

Where exactly is df_new stored? If this was regular python, I would guess somewhere in memory. But is this true for PySpark as well? Or is it just some kind of reference? Is it persisted on disk somewhere in hdfs?

Comment: AFAIK the contents of `df_new` aren't actually stored anywhere at the moment. Spark is lazy, so it doesn't evaluate `df_new` until it needs to. For now it just stores the instructions needed to create `df_new`.

Answer (score 1):

`df_new` is *a transformation* from `my_big_hdfs_df` after applying the condition in `where` function.

Or in other words, `df_new` is *a logical plan* set to be performed on the data as soon as an `action` will be called upon.

Data is not touched until a*n action* such as `show()`, `count()` `foreach()` etc are called.

As soon as *an action* is called, *data is transformed* and all the *transformations are stored in memory*. Sometimes *they are spilled to disk when `persist()` is called*. And *saved to disk when action to save is called*.